# Not able to send a scheduled message in PHP IRC-BOT

Tags: php, sockets, bots, irc

I’m on my way to develop a simple irc bot in php. 
The half above is an implementation for IRC bot from scratch ( connecting a socket …. etc )
The feature I want to add is “Schedule notification”
When the specific time comes, some messages are sent.

For example,
when time `Tue Apr 19 16:32` comes, some notification message is sent.

So if you set something like  `(date("D") == "Tue" && date("H") == 15)`,
this is supposed to keep sending message until 16:00 comes.

**But the as soon as the bot comes into a channel, It stops sending messages.**

I assume this is caused by the socket connection, however I don’t really know the clue.

```
<?php

// Time zone setting
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

// Our bot's configuration parameters.
$server = '192.168.59.103';
$port = 6667;
$nickname = 'Bot';
$ident = 'Bot';
$gecos = 'Bot v1.0';
$channel = '#bot-test';


// Connect to the network
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$error = socket_connect($socket, $server, $port);

// Add some error handling in case connection was not successful.
if ($socket === false){
    $errorCode = socket_last_error();
    $errorString = socket_strerror($errorCode);
    die("Error $errorCode: $errorString \n");
}

// Send the registration info.
socket_write($socket, "NICK $nickname\r\n");
socket_write($socket, "USER $ident * 8 :$gecos\r\n");

// Finally, loop until the socket closes.
while (is_resource($socket)) {

    // Fetch the data from the socket
    $data = trim(socket_read($socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ));
    echo $data . "\n";

    // Splitting the data into chunks
    $d = explode(' ', $data);

    // Padding the array avoids ugly undefined offset erros.
    $d = array_pad ($d, 10, '');

    // Our ping handler.
    // Ping: $servername.
    if ($d[0] === 'PING') {
        socket_write($socket, 'PONG ' . $d[1] . "\r\n");
    }

    if ($d[1] === '376' || $d[1] === '422') {
        socket_write($socket, 'JOIN ' . $channel . "\r\n");
    }

    // Bot collections

    // "$d" parameter format
    // [0]                      [1]     [2]           [3]
    // :Nickname!ident@hostname PRIVMSG #bot-test :@arukas.

    // Scheduler bot
    if (date("D") == "Tue" && date("H") == 15) {
        $saying = "REALLY SLEEPY!!";
        socket_write($socket, 'PRIVMSG ' . "CIRC1989" . " :$saying\r\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is broken on the read/write logic part - Your current code always assume read something (will sleep until something happens), then write something. You need to add buffers and use poll/select. I assume php as at least one of them.

Pseudocode that should work:

```
readbuffer[]
writebuffer[]

while (no_error)
{
  if (writebuffer not empty)
  {
    select(socket, want_to_write, want_to_read, timeout_until_next_event);
  } else {
    select(socket, 0, want_to_read, timeout_until_next_event);
  }
  if (select return can write)
  {
    retval = write(socket, writebuffer);
    if (no_error)
      writebuffer.removefromstart(retval);
  }
  if (select return can read)
  {
    retval = read(socket, readbuffer + offset already filled);
    if (no_error)
    {
      parse as much as possible in readbuffer, removing data as parsed;
    }
  }
  check_timers();
}
```

Comment: Note that timeout_until_next_event should be as high as you really want to get away with (as many seconds as the next timer tick for your scheduled event, really). Cycling too much in the while loop with a low select timeout can cause excessive cpu usage.